# How can I get the Acces-token from Header with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, oauth, httpclient

I have a problem. I'd like to get the access-token from Header in my API. I am use this code below to access into my service. I am using C# and HttpClient.

```
static async Task Login()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.xxxxxx.com/auth/");
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", "xxx@localhost.com"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "hello123")
            });

            var result = await client.PostAsync("sign_in", content);
            string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
        }
    }
```

But, I am not able to get the access-token from header, someone here could help me with this issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the [HttpContent.Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.headers(v=vs.118).aspx) collection.

```
 var result = await client.PostAsync("sign_in", content);
 var token = result.Headers.GetValues("access-token").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get easily by following code:

```
static async Task Login([FromHeader] string headerToken)
```

But to get this **headerToken**, variable name should be same in header also.
[headerToken example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJDVs.png)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31851822)